# Dynamic reference in excel formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following array formula which works for what I want to do but I'm trying to change the formula when a user selects a value.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$70,SMALL(IF($A$2:$B$70=$A$121,ROW($A$2:$B$70)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)
```

It's used for a monthly report and the user will choose from a drop down the day of the month, e.g 1,2,3 - 31.

So if the user selects 1 from the drop down menu I want the formula to use the above formula.
If they select 2 for example I want the formula to move over a column so it would change to

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$70,SMALL(IF($A$2:$C$70=$A$121,ROW($A$2:$C$70)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)
```

and so on moving over a column at a time.

It this possible at all or can it even be done without VBA?

I have an example of what I want done on the following link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MDOzoQxYLgW-UOyljZsMwSu8zyAB7O2k1V-bTNP5_F0/edit?usp=sharing

All the data is on the first tab called staff. Each employee has a row and the duty assigned under the corresponding day column.
On the Roster tab it summarises each day. So what I am trying to get to happen is when you choose the day of the month (or preferably the actual date) the sheet changes to reflect the data.

At the moment the code I have working does for just Day 1 because the column references are coded into the formula. I was hoping to somehow choose 6 for example from the drop down and then the formula will map chosen day to the corresponding range in the raw data and update the formula and change the formula from `Staff!$A$2:$B$68 to Staff!$A$2:$G$68`.

If the formula finds no more entries if shows #NUM! but I intended to use the function ISERROR() to replace #NUM! with "".

This is what I'm trying to achieve it if makes sense?

Comment: You might be able to do something with the `OFFSET` function.

Comment: a) Yes, it can be done. b) what cell holds the 1 or 2 from the drop down list? c) never mind

Comment: I am just setting up the other sheet but the drop down can be any cell really. Is there anywhere I can upload my example to show like jsfiddle?

Comment: I have the formula working for the column but if i move to the 2nd for example I can't get the result correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here/ You are returning the value from column A so the first range can be `$A$2:$A$70` and that means you don't need the 1 to specify the *column_num*. The `IF` statement was covering A2:C70 when you really only want either B2:70 or C2:C70 depending on the 1 or 2.

Assuming that A122 has either a 1 or 2 in it then,

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$70, SMALL(IF(INDEX($B$2:$C$70, 0, $A$122) = $A$121, ROW($1:$69)), ROW(1:1)))
```

Standard non-array alternative,

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$70, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$69)+(INDEX($B$2:$C$70, 0, $A$122) <> $A$121)*1E+99,, ), ROW(1:1)))
```

Comment: I'll try this thanks but the values in the table are mainly alphanumeric values. Will let you know how I get on. Row 1 will contain the days of the month and column a will contain a persons name. Hence B2 to the right and down will contain all the alphanumeric data.

Comment: Sample data together with expected results can answer many questions.

Comment: You can post redacted non-maro data to any public file storage area. GoogleDrive, DropBox and ONeDrive are preferred due to low impact advertizing. Post the link to the PUBLICALLY SHARED file back here. Be sure sure that you describe what the results you are trying to achieve or it will be nothing more than a data dump.

Comment: I have updated the question above to hopefully reflect what you asked for

Comment: Any one advice on doing this, I've been trying and think it might only be possible with VBA?